# How can i get only particular text from a script (web crawler/python)

Tags: python, web-crawler

Please refer to the photo I have attached. I have print a string which is script from the website, but I want only the particular text which in the double quotes(as the red underline in the pic). How can I revise the code which is purple box in the pic?

Thank you

[web crawler issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjO5O.jpg)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

u = 'https://web.pcc.gov.tw/prkms/tender/common/bulletion/readBulletion?querySentence=5G&tenderStatusType=%E6%8B%9B%E6%A8%99&sortCol=TENDER_NOTICE_DATE&timeRange=111&pageSize=10'
r = requests.get(u)
soup = bs(r.text,'html.parser')

for case in soup.tbody.select('tr'):
    print(case.select('td')[2].string)
    print(case.select('td')[3].a.script)
    print('https://web.pcc.gov.tw'+case.select('td')[3].a['href'])
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

u = 'https://web.pcc.gov.tw/prkms/tender/common/bulletion/readBulletion?querySentence=5G&tenderStatusType=%E6%8B%9B%E6%A8%99&sortCol=TENDER_NOTICE_DATE&timeRange=111&pageSize=10'
r = requests.get(u)
soup = bs(r.text,'html.parser')

def findString(text):
    match = re.search(r"\"(\w*)\"", text)
    return match.group(1) if match else ""

for case in soup.tbody.select('tr'):
    print(case.select('td')[2].string)
    print(findString(case.select('td')[3].a.script.text))
    print('https://web.pcc.gov.tw'+case.select('td')[3].a['href'])
    print("")
```

Few things to note:

1. `case.select('td')[3].a.script` is a `bs4.element.Tag`, you need to use `.text` to get the text inside the tag
2. To find text between quotation mark in a string, you can use `re.search()`.

Comment: Thank you!! I have tried your code but the result now came blank. The note is helpful :)

Comment: Can you show me your result ? I just copy and paste all the codes into jupyter notebook and everything is fine.

Comment: Result as below, some text will come as well but the second & forth came blank.
========
長庚大學 5G基地台測試教學系統詳規範共1ST web.pcc.gov.tw/prkms/urlSelector/common/tpam?pk=NzAwMDE1MzI= 南臺學校財團法人南臺科技大學 web.pcc.gov.tw/prkms/urlSelector/common/tpam?pk=NTM4MjEwODU= 國立臺中教育大學 5G基地台模擬器UERANSIM運行平台等一批 web.pcc.gov.tw/prkms/urlSelector/common/tpam?pk=NTM4MjMwMzk= 國立臺灣科學教育館 web.pcc.gov.tw/prkms/urlSelector/common/tpam?pk=NTM4MTkyNDQ=

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ytung-dev. I have solve it after few trying. 
 I replaced  `match = re.search(r"\"(\w*)\"", text)` with `match = re.search(r'\"(.*?)\"', text)` .

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

u = 'https://web.pcc.gov.tw/prkms/tender/common/bulletion/readBulletion?querySentence=5G&tenderStatusType=%E6%8B%9B%E6%A8%99&sortCol=TENDER_NOTICE_DATE&timeRange=111&pageSize=10'
r = requests.get(u)
soup = bs(r.text,'html.parser')

def findString(text):
    match = re.search(r'\"(.*?)\"', text)
    return match.group(1) if match else ""

for case in soup.tbody.select('tr'):
    print(case.select('td')[2].string)
    print(findString(case.select('td')[3].a.script.text))
    print('https://web.pcc.gov.tw'+case.select('td')[3].a['href'])
    print("")
```